# SERVFAIL on ANY query

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, dns-hosting, dig

We have a CNAME entry that points to an Amazon Elastic Load Balancer instance. For some reason, my mobile app can resolve this entry on wifi, but not 3G -- I imagine it's talking to a different name server on 3G than Wifi and getting a different answer.

When done through a local name server, an ANY query looks like this (parts redacted to protect the innocent):

```
; <<>> DiG 9.6.0-APPLE-P2 <<>> elb.foo.com ANY
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 1051
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 4, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;elb.foo.com.       IN  ANY

;; ANSWER SECTION:
elb.foo.com.    299 IN  CNAME   elb-foo-com-12345.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com.
elb-foo-com-12345.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com.  1 IN SOA ns-123.amazon.com. dns.amazon.com. 1288881125 3600 900 7776000 60
elb-foo-com-12345.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com.  600 IN NS ns-123.amazon.com.
elb-foo-com-12345.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com.  60 IN A 174.129.0.0
```

However, when I query directly against the name server (@dns1.registrar-servers.com) I get the following answer:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.6.0-APPLE-P2 <<>> @dns1.registrar-servers.com elb.foo.com ANY
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 7735
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;elb.foo.com.       IN  ANY

;; ANSWER SECTION:
elb.foo.com.    300 IN  CNAME   elb-foo-com-12345.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com.
```

The interesting part here is "WARNING: recursion requested but not available" and "SERVFAIL". I imagine I need to talk to my DNS provider, but what should my talking points be and what should I do if I cannot resolve the problem?

EDIT: Using the Android "Ping and DNS" app I tried to resolve the domain name. On 3G, I get timeouts or "type not found" for all but CNAME and SOA types. I think the DNS server used is 69.78.96.14, according to the app.

Comment: please don't redact your domain name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazingly enough, it seems that it was this issue:

http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/thread.jspa?threadID=53360

The plumbing in Verizon's DNS system apparently couldn't handle the large-ish CNAME entry and entries were timing out. Renaming the load balancer name to a single character fixed it.

Comment: For some reason, a lot of people seem to think that supporting DNS over TCP is optional. It is not.

Answer (score 0):

The "recursion requested" warning shouldn't be relevant - most authoritative servers will continue to dish out authoritative answers even if recursion was requested, which is the default for `dig`.

I've just used Google to find a domain that is hosted in the same place and it works as expected.  However trying some other domain that's known not to be hosted there produces `SERVFAIL`.

This is slightly odd - the normal error should be `REFUSED`, but it indicates that your domain simply isn't correctly provisioned on that server.

Answer (score -1):

This is a better solution, create an alias in Amazon's Route 53.  Of course it requires that you have your DNS through them.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/HowToAliasRRS.html

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! We really do prefer that answers contain content not pointers to content. Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.